# Swarm Robot Simulation

Tags: webots, swarm

Both **V-rep** and **Webots** simulator says that they can simulate multiple robots. Is these simulators are capable for simulate swarm robots? Can I simulate the swarm intelligence algorithms like ACO, BeeClust algorithm, Stick pulling Algorithm, Occlusion Based Collective pushing etc. on these simulators? Which robot I have to select for implementing above algorithms? For implementing these algorithms which simulator will be better? Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. Edited question with more explanations. I saw some projects on Github which is integrated these simulators with ROS. That is why I think these simulators are not alone capable enough to do that job.  That is why asked so.

Comment: try contacting the two companies that publish the software and check their forums

Comment: i wonder if you may be able to do the same with Processing .... https://processing.org/examples/flocking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to separate between simulation and artificial intelligence. An environment for simulating hundreds of robots on the screen is called a game engine. It can be realized with standard programming languages for example Python/pygame. The user creates an array of objects and each objects has a position and a speed value. The graphics engine displays all the objects on the screen. This is called a realtime simulation.

The other part is the artificial intelligence to control the objects. Without an AI, the robots in the simulation has to be controlled manually or by a random generator. They are displayed at the screen with smoothly 60 frames per second, but it's unknown how to move them right so that robots are solving a task. In general, a simulator for displaying hundreds of objects is easy to realize. The more advanced part is to create the AI which drives the objects autonomously.

Simulators like Webots, V-Rep, Gazebo, pygame or Unity3D are the environment in which a robotics controller is developed. They are providing the graphics and the underlying physics engine. They are working as a game construction set in which the user can script a game.

Comment: Could you please explain, are you saying I have to use Pygame and Python instead of Webots or V-rep?

Comment: @ArunKS Most simulators are very equal. They are providing the same functionality and allowing to test out robotics controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Any general purpose robot simulator like V-REP or Webots can get your task done, though with not the best support for swarm robots in particular. [ARGoS](https://www.argos-sim.info/) is a good platform for swarm robot simulation, maintained well enough with active contributors and shall allow you to inherently have support for centralized/de-centralized control.

The most common swarm robots are the Kilobots and the Khepera and ARGoS supports both of them.

Answer (score 1):

The [ARGoS](https://github.com/ilpincy/argos3) simulator specifically targets swarm robotics development. There is also a really awesome swarm robotics programming language, [Buzz](https://github.com/MISTLab/Buzz), that plugs into ARGoS. There is even a ROSBuzz version. Lastly, I recently discovered this fantastic repo named [TensorSwarm](https://github.com/TensorSwarm/TensorSwarm) for reinforcement learning of robot swarms that plugs into ARGoS.